# map list with regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

I have a string that looks like:

```
(((ENGL 210) or (COMM 243) or (COMM 205)) and (ECEN 314) and (ECEN 325))
```

I want to transform it into:

```
((ENGL 210 or COMM 243 or COMM 205) and ECEN 314 and ECEN 325)
```

Basically map everything in the string of the form `(cccc ddd)` to `cccc ddd` where `c` is a character and `d` is a number.

I know I can extract all such strings using `re` but I want to map them back to the new format. What will be the cleanest way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Post the code to "extract all such strings using re"

Comment: Sorry about that. I wrote it as: `re.findall(r'(\(\w\w\w\w \d\d\d\))', string)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

t = '(((ENGL 210) or (COMM 243) or (COMM 205)) and (ECEN 314) and (ECEN 325))'
re.sub(r'\(([A-Z]{4} [\d]{3})\)', r'\1', t)
```

result

```
'((ENGL 210 or COMM 243 or COMM 205) and ECEN 314 and ECEN 325)'
```

explanation, re.sub first argument

> `r'` is going to define a regular expresion inside single quotes
>
> > `\(` is to match the opening parenthesis, **this is the one that you want to remove**
> >
> > `(` opening prenthesis to define a new "group". The things inside this will be stored as a matching "group" as regex group number 1
> >
> > > *matching group #1*
> > >
> > > `[A-Z]{4}` match four characters uppercase letter
> > >
> > > match also a space
> > >
> > > `[\d]{4}` match also four digits
> >
> > `)` close group number 1
> >
> > `\)` close matching parenthesis **(the other one you want to remove)**
>
> `'` close the regex

explanation, re.sub second argument

> `r'` is going to define a regular expresion inside single quotes
>
> > `\1` restore the group number one matched in previous argument
>
> `'` close the regex

Answer (score 2):

The following should work:

```
>>> re.sub(r'\((\w{4} \d{3})\)', r'\1', s)
'((ENGL 210 or COMM 243 or COMM 205) and ECEN 314 and ECEN 325)'
```

`re.sub` will match the pattern consisting of:

- an opening parenthesis `\(`
- a first group of `(...)`

  - 4 letters `\w{4}`
  - a space
  - three digits `\d{3}`
- and a closing parenthesis `\)`

For each match we replace it with the content of the first group (`\1`) and we have the needed result.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) to do this:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '(((ENGL 210) or (COMM 243) or (COMM 205)) and (ECEN 314) and (ECEN 325))'
>>> re.sub(r'\(([^()]+)\)', r'\1', s)
'((ENGL 210 or COMM 243 or COMM 205) and ECEN 314 and ECEN 325)'
```

And if you want to be strict on the format:

```
>>> re.sub(r'\((\w+ \d+)\)', r'\1', s)
```